# Função "OnTriggerEnter2D" é executada mesmo com o "Is Trigger" desabilitado

Tags: unity3d

Tenho o GameObject "player" com um box colider com a opção "Is Trigger" desmarcada, ou seja, não é um trigger.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No script associado ao player existe a função "OnTriggerEnter2D":

```
//...
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D o) {
    print(o.tag);
}
```

Quando o player colide com um objecto qualquer, ele executa essa função, apesar do box collider não ser um trigger.

Não tenho mais nenhum box collider associado ao player e não tenho objectos filhos.

Estou usando a versão Unity 5.2.2f1.

Comment: Não consigo ver a Imagem Filipe tem algum filho neste objeto que poderia estar com o collider marcado como gatilho?

Comment: @Frohlich não tem filhos (a informação estava na pergunta), mas conforme a resposta do Mateus abaixo, entendi como funciona o trigger. Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script vinculada ao objeto com o Collider tem que estar com o On Trigger ligado, seu player não precisa de um Collider OnTrigger se o objeto que tem está definição já tem.

Comment: Já entendi Mateus, a função "OnTrigger" no script associado ao player será invocada quando o player colidir com outro objecto que contém um collider do tipo "trigger". Eu pensava que o próprio objecto tinha que ter um trigger que executaria a função no seu próprio script e não de outro objecto.